# Why do you need to attach or reference and object when accessing another class variable in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example, If i want to access the integer health in another class, i have to create a reference off that class and attach it to an object either in the inspector or programatically. How come i cannot just access the public integer without attaching the object? Example code

```
 public class Game : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public int health;
 }

 public class player : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public Game gameScript;
 gameScript.health = 10;  //this will cause nullpointer error if not attached to a gameobject or
                          //public GameObject test;
                          //gameScript = test.GetComponent<testscript> ();

 }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what is behavior you'd like to achieve? I.e. you have 10 objects with "health" - show what kind of code you expect to write so you can get "health" from object you are interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be **able** to **access other values** in Unity **without** attaching it to **GameObject**, you have to make sure that you don't **inherit** **MonoBehaviour**. Once you inherit **MonoBehaviour**, you will **no longer** be able to **access** the values or functions in the **other** script. That's how Unity is made.

So change:

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public int health;
 }
```

to

```
public class Game
 {
 public int health;
 }
```

Also you must use the **new** keyword before you access the value or your class would be null and crash your program.

```
public Game gameScript;
 gameScript.health = 10;
```

should be changed to something like this:

```
public Game gameScript = new Game();
 gameScript.health = 10;
```

Since you will be accessing your class from other classes, you need to make your health variable **static** and access directly. If you don't, you will have many instances of health variable each time you use the **new** keyword.

By making your variable static, you could just do `Game.health = 10;` directly without using the keyword or creating another instance of it. Below is an example:

```
 public class Game
 {
 public static int health;
 }
```

then you can access it with

```
Game.health = 10;
```

**EDIT**:

**GET/SET METHOD**

```
 public class Game
     {
     public static int health;

    public static int getHealth(){
    return Game.health;
    }

    public static void setHealth(int tempHealth){
    Game.health = tempHealth;
      }
    }
```

Then to access this from other classes, you could do:

```
Debug.Log(Game.getHealth().toString());
```

To Modify,

```
Game.setHealth(10);
```

I did compile this but it should work.

Comment: Nice explanation! what about adding a getter and setter? public Game gameScript{get;set;} , can you use this without instead of using the new keyword?

Comment: I am not sure about get/set. But you can create getter/setter functions to get and set the health instead of using the built in one. You can also make these functions to be public and static so that it can be accessed directly without the new keyword. need an example?

Comment: an example would be great, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Well for this, you have to instantiate the game object, but if you want to just allow it as is change it to: public static int health; or put a getter/setter method to retrieve this value "health". C++ and Java have to have instantiated objects to retrieve from to set a value/ get a value from any attribute.

Comment: Some explanation and example would be great.